# How the derivatives are different if sign changes.

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation

I have this expression $$\frac{1}{(1 - x) ^ 2}$$
I need the derivative of this expression. So I calculated it, no big deal. However something has crossed my mind. Mathematically $(1 - x) ^ 2 = (x - 1) ^ 2$ isn't it ? So why is the derivatives of $1 / (1 - x) ^ 2$ and $1 / (x - 1) ^ 2$ are different ? Given that we take the derivative of the function inside, the minus sign will appear in the first expression but not in the second. I would be grateful if somebody could explain the behavior to me.

I calculated the results of these derivatives and confirmed from the website http://www.derivative-calculator.net/

The derivative of $1 / (x - 1)^2$ is $-2/(x-1)^3$

And the derivative of $1 / (1 - x)^2$ is $2/(x-1)^3$

Aren't they different ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: They are equal, you should do the calculation again. In one case there is an inner derivative (chain rule) that compensates the different sign.

Comment: I used http://www.derivative-calculator.net/ which gave different results, that was the thing that confused me.

Comment: @Rockybilly: Which different results do you get? Are they "different" in a more substantial way than $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ are?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The first expression has an extra minus sign. Try 1 / (x - 1)^2 and 1 / (1- x)^2.

Comment: @Rockybilly please edit your question to tell us what site you are using and the results you are getting.  Detail like this needs to be in the question and not comments.  It may be that the site is buggy or that the two answers may look different but actually be equivalent.

Comment: @WarrenHill I updated it.

Comment: @Rockybilly: When I try that site I get $\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$ in the second case, not $\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$.

Comment: Darn, I knew I was overlooking something, Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

It isn't different.
There's a minus sign introduced by the derivative of (1-x), but there's also an odd power of (1-x), which is the second minus sign when compared to (x-1)